# Load application class from plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

In a Grails 1.1 plugin, I'm trying to load a class from the main application using the following code:

```
class MyClass {
  static Map getCustomConfig(String configName){
    return new ConfigSlurper().
      parse(ApplicationHolder.application.classLoader.loadClass(configName))                    
  }
}
```

Where `configName` is the name of the class in `$MAIN_APP/grails-app/conf` containing the configuration info. However, when the code above runs within a unit test `applicationHolder.application` returns null, causing the method above to throw a `NullPointerException`. A Grails [JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1576) was created for this problem, but it has been marked as fixed despite the fact that problem appears to still exist.

I know that within the plugin descriptor class I can access the main application (an instance of `GrailsApplication`) via the implicit `application` variable. But the code shown above is in not in the plugin descriptor.

Is there a way that I can load a class from the main application within a plugin (but outside the plugin descriptor)?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there are 2 possible answers.

**The Right Answer**

GrailsApplication is not available in unit tests, so for the code above to work it should be an integration test

**The Hack that Works**

Change

```
parse(ApplicationHolder.application.classLoader.loadClass(configName))
```

to

```
parse(MyClass.classLoader.loadClass(configName))
```